# What is the best approach to copy directories?

Tags: files, rhel, rsync, scp

What is the best approach to copy folders to remote machine (in my case we need to copy everything from `/etc/yum.repo.d` to remote machine)? Using `rsync -av` or `scp -rp`?

```
# scp -rp /etc/yum.repos.d/* master100:/etc/yum.repos.d 
# rsync -av /etc/yum.repos.d/* master100:/etc/yum.repos.d
```

Comment: This answer might be able to help you understand the difference between the commands. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20257021/7499402

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prefer to use `rsync`.  It is simpler to remember, because as you show, the most common options match the syntax of `cp`.

Technically `rsync` might not be installed on some systems where `scp` is available.  However the features of `rsync` are super-useful.  As a result, it will *usually* be installed, and it is useful to get practice using it.

For cases like you show, you might sometimes want to use `rsync --delete`.  This is useful even for local files (`cp` has no `--delete` option).  However it is also super-dangerous.  When you write an `rsync --delete` command, you should *always* run it first in `-n` mode, to see what it will do without actually doing it.

(It's particularly dangerous because rsync interprets trailing `/` on the source as meaning something different to everyone else (more similar to trailing `/.`), and path-completion with the TAB key will automatically include the trailing `/` if the path is a directory.  This can cause problems even without `--delete`, by overwriting the wrong files or cluttering the wrong directory with files that don't make sense.  I assume rsync's behaviour pre-dates the widespread use of path completion.)

Comment: so for summary regarding my case to copy only the repo folders what is better?

Comment: @yael edited first sentence for clarity.