# what is the right approach to copy folder content that include links

Tags: linux, rsync, scp, hard-link, links

we have the following folders / links /files under /usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/zookeeper folder

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 794542 Apr  1  2017 zookeeper-3.4.6.2.6.0.3-8.jar
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root   4096 Mar 28  2018 doc
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root     17 Mar 28  2018 etc
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   4096 Mar 28  2018 lib
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root     17 Mar 28  2018 man
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     29 Mar 28  2018 zookeeper.jar -> zookeeper-3.4.6.2.6.0.3-8.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     26 Mar 28  2018 conf -> /etc/zookeeper/2.6.0.3-8/0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   4096 Oct 16 17:07 bin
[root@master01 zookeeper]# pwd
/usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/zookeeper
```

we want to copy all content under /usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/zookeeper to other machine - lets say - master02 machine

what is the right command to copy the content  under /usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/zookeeper , from current machine to target machine ( save all links and permissions )

Comment: This isn't very different to your old question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388186/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the much used `-a` option of `rsync`:

> ```
>     -a, --archive               archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)
> ```

Which will provide what you need:

> ```
>     -r, --recursive             recurse into directories
>     -l, --links                 copy symlinks as symlinks
>     -p, --perms                 preserve permissions
>     -t, --times                 preserve modification times
>     -g, --group                 preserve group
>     -o, --owner                 preserve owner (super-user only)
>     -D                          same as --devices --specials
>         --devices               preserve device files (super-user only)
>         --specials              preserve special files
> ```

Add the `-v` option for verbosity and you get:

```
rsync -av /usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/zookeeper/ master02:/usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/zookeeper
```

You may want to add the `-delete` option to cleanup destination directory:

> ```
>         --delete                delete extraneous files from dest dirs
> ```